# Do AC bonuses from spells stack with AC from equipment?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, equipment, armor-class

For classes like the Bloodrager that can wear armor and shields and cast arcane spells:

- Does the armor bonus to AC from the Mage Armor spell stack with the armor bonus to AC from an actual armor worn by the character?
- Does the shield bonus to AC from the Shield spell stack with the shield bonus to AC from an actual shield equipped?
- Do these spells (Mage Armor and Shield) stack with each other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Pathfinder, **bonuses of the same type do not stack.**

*Mage Armor* and regular armor (full plate, etc.) both provide an **armor** bonus, so they do not stack.  The same can be said for a shield and the spell *Shield* — they both apply a **shield** bonus to AC.  When they don't stack, you use the higher of the two bonuses.

This means that *Shield* and *Mage Armor* **do** stack, because they provide bonuses of different types — *Mage Armor* grants an armor bonus and *Shield* grants a shield bonus.